# Trains overview image

Tags: sets, trains, city

I'm looking for an overview image of all trains ever released by LEGO. With trains I mean train sets containing locomotives and wagons that run on train tracks.

There is a beautiful [image from Jeroen de Haan](http://brickfetish.com/art/dehaan_2003_1010.jpg), which shows all trains from 1981 to 2003, but it's a little outdated.

[image: Lego trains 1981 - 2003]

Comment: As a starting point we've listed out the [all the trains since 2003 here](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1149/56)

Answer (score 4):

There is a new project called [Train Poster v2](https://trainposterv2.wordpress.com/) which is making a new poster with all trains from the 1960's until today. It is still a work in progress as of 2016.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a direct continuation of the poster, your best bet would be to contact [the author on his website](http://brickfetish.com/).

It wouldn't be too hard to remake the models yourself as all the software is available out there for free. The author has used LDraw to view the models and POV-Ray to render them. You can find the details [here](http://brickfetish.com/art/dehaan_2003.html).

Fortunately Eurobricks has a [database of official sets designed by fans in LDraw](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=48285).

However, there are only 1927 sets available (as of April 2015) and most of the train sets released after 2003 are not available.

There are [4748 sets designed using the LEGO Digital Designer (LDD) software](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226). If you open a LDD file in LDD, you can export the file as an LDraw file.  (File -> Export Model / <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>). Even with the most up-to-date LDraw parts library, you may find that not every LDD brick will be available in your LDraw model.

If you cannot find all the models in LDraw or LDD, you may be able to find the files created in other LEGO CAD software or you can recreate the models yourself using your favourite LEGO CAD software using the instructions (which should be available on the [LEGO site](http://service.lego.com/en-gb/buildinginstructions)).

LDD would probably be the best choice, as you can render the files using [LDD2PovRay](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=71654).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very useful information. If and when I find the time I'll try to do it myself. Hopefully to be continued...